# WIA set document size to scan C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, com, wia

I'm scanning documents with WIA. All works good but scanning page result is not A4 format. How to say WIA to scan whole document? When I scan, page result is cropped to Letter format.
Here is code:

```
 WIA.Item Item = _scannerDevice.Items[1] as WIA.Item;
 WIA.ImageFile wiaImage = null;
 Item.Properties["6147"].set_Value(dpi);
 Item.Properties["6148"].set_Value(dpi);
 //start from x=0; y=0;
 Item.Properties["6149"].set_Value(0);
 Item.Properties["6150"].set_Value(0);

 Item.Properties["6151"].set_Value(width);
 Item.Properties["6152"].set_Value(height);
 wiaImage = (ImageFile)_scannDialog.ShowTransfer(Item, wiaFormatJPEG, false);                      
 if (wiaImage.FileData != null)
   {
       WIA.Vector vector = wiaImage.FileData;
      _image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[])vector.get_BinaryData()));
       OnScannComplete(_image);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you need to use the appropriate properties for Page sizes.

You need to set WIA_IPS_PAGE_SIZE (ID 3097) to 0 (which means A4).

For some samples/source to set the page size to A4 see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630196%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa360096%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- [Set page size using WIA (with scanner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245675/set-page-size-using-wia-with-scanner/2848760#2848760)

Comment: I've tried to make this Item.Properties["3097"].set_Value(0); but it's not working. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: currently not on my dev machine... what value have you for `width` and `height` ? also read esp. the last link I posted.

Comment: Last link isn't woking. I receive exception "Value does not fall within the expected range." in last else if expression.

Comment: Now i have dpi = 150, width=1275 and height=1750. It's working but file is too big

Comment: what do you mean by "file is too big" ?

Comment: My mistake. I mean is to big. File size is about 7 Mbyte