# WIA Scanner DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS (3087) value is 3

Tags: c#, winforms, wia

I am having some problem trying to use the ADF (Feeder) Mode with my Scanner.

The property WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS of my device seems strange because is equal to 3.

Any idea about the meaning?

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/wa/wiadocumenthandlingstatusflags.html

http://www.gnome.eu/Morena/doc/api/constant-values.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ea462e5f-e980-4b2c-a7c7-a64e0773e4b5/wia-scanning-code-not-working-as-it-should?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: The 3 status is an OR of status 1 with 2 in FIRST link.

Comment: The default page size is wrong.  It doesn't match the size paper you are loading.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245675/set-page-size-using-wia-with-scanner

Comment: @jdweng Thank you! I didn't know that